# Как данные введенные на форму отправить на базу данных

Tags: php

Что сделал неправильно? И как сделать, чтобы id, которые будут совпадать не будет добавляться?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>My page</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="main">
   <?php 
   include("header.php"); ?>
   <?php 
   include ("menu.php"); ?>
   <div class=magazin>

<form action="admin.php" method="post">
   ID<br>
  <input type="numeral" name="id"><br>
  Name<br>
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  Price<br>
  <input type="numeral" name="price"><br>
  Description<br>
  <input type="text" name="description"><br>
  Src<br>
  <input type="text" name="src"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="insert">
 </form>

 <?php 
 $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw","litle");

 

 

 
 


 if ($_POST["insert"]) {
 
 
 
 $id=($_POST['id']);
 $name=($_POST['name']);
 $price=($_POST['price']);
 $description=($_POST['description']);
 $src=($_POST['src']);

$sql=" INSERT INTO `products` (`id`,`name`,`price`,`description`,`src`)
 VALUES ('$id,'$name','$price','$description','$src')";

 mysqli_query($link,$sql);

 echo "Тавар успешно дабавлень";

 mysqli_close($link);

 
}


  ?>


<?php 
  include("footer.php"); ?>
  
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле id в вашей базе данных должно быть PRIMARY_KEY и AUTO_INCREMENT и создаваться автоматически. id не записывается в базу вручную.

Код у вас должен быть такой:

```
<?php 
if ($_POST["insert"]) {


    $link = new Mysqli("localhost","root","usbw","litle");

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $src = $_POST['src'];

    $sql = " INSERT INTO `products` (`name`,`price`,`description`,`src`)
    VALUES ('$name','$price','$description','$src')";

    if($link->query($sql)) {
        echo "Тавар успешно дабавлень"; 
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
        <?php 
        include("header.php"); ?>
        <?php 
        include ("menu.php"); ?>
        <div class=magazin>

        <form action="admin.php" method="post">
            Name<br>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            Price<br>
            <input type="numeral" name="price"><br>
            Description<br>
            <input type="text" name="description"><br>
            Src<br>
            <input type="text" name="src"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="insert">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У меня вместо ид пищет нулл автаматический А как можно ИД ввадить и чтоб они не савпадали